# Find coefficients in a sum of product with equality constraint

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve this problem and can't really map it a correct framework and perhaps a solution.

A1*C1 + A2*C2 + A3*C3 <= X

C1,C3 and C3 are number of units of goods and are given.
A1, A2, A3 are the unit costs for each unit but not given to you.
X - Total cost and is given. Total cost cannot exceed X.

Find solution for A1 - A3. I originally thought of this has Knapsack problem or a variation on coin change problem and could not really map it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem does not seem to be fully formulated since, as stated, it admits an infinity of solutions, eg (A1,A2,A3) = (X/C1,0,0) and (0,X/C2,0) and many more. It has a flavour of a linear programming problem but lacks the optimization part

Comment: Please add additional details and clean this question up. The title talks about equality, the described problem is about inequality. The tags: optimization -> there is no notion of optimization in your task. This is a problem as already commented, as there is no reason against the 0,0,0 solution (give x is nonnegative). Tags DP, combinatorics and knapsack are all discrete or combinatorial optimization, where your problem, as currently stated, is a non-discrete problem (no integrality-constraints).

Comment: As above, it is an ill-defined problem and has infinite solutions. You need to add more constraints and you can use linear programming or non-linear programing to solve it depending on whether the other constraints are non-linear. At the moment, pick any values for A1 and A2, then solve the inequality for A3.